# storing many attributes for a single record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a model and table called product.  Each product will have around 100 attributes.  Each attribute will be a string.  Should I simply add all of these attributes to the product table?  Or is it better to create several child models and access them by has_many / belongs_to associations?  I plan to have a page that will load all of these attributes.  I will be the only person setting these attributes.  Are there other ways to consider doing this?  Perhaps I could save everything into a single text data type row and format it all somehow or even just write it all out in regular HTML.

Comment: What are some examples of attributes?  Does every record have the same attributes?

Comment: Yes they will have the same attributes.  Some examples: price, dimensions, weight, etc.

Comment: The advantages to having every thing in one table is simplicity, speed of execution, easier editing especially if you use data-binding controls.  The disadvantage is to add or modify an attribute you must change the DB and the code.  I've seen designs where the attributes are kept in separate tables along with the type of the attribute.  It is much slower and more complicated because the code has to deal with attribute type.  However, adding attributes is much easier.  Since you have a one to one relationship record/attribute and each is attribute is different, I'd put them all in one table.

Comment: you have also the option of storing these in a serialized form in database (may be hash) and using it..The disadvantage is that you will not be able to query from these columns (write conditions in SQL). If you dont need to query from these columns (like `select * from products where price > 100`), you can consider it.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest the following design.

```
Attribute Table -- AttributeId (primary key), AttributeName
Product Table   -- ProductId   (primary key), 
                   other product related informations(except attributes).
ProductAttribute Table -- ProductId(foreign key), AttributeId(foreign key)
```

If each attribute will have different values for each product, then you may consider ProductAttribute table like this:

```
ProductAttribute Table -- ProductId(foreign key), AttributeId(foreign key), 
                          AttributeValue
```

**EDIT**:

You don't need to make 100 tables. You need 3 tables according to my concept. Now, the `Attribute` table will have 100 rows, one for each attribute. Suppose you have 5 attributes `a1, a2, a3, a4, a5` and two products `p1,p2`. Then, the tables will look like:

```
Attribute
---------

AttributeId | AttributeName
---------------------------
1           | a1
2           | a2
3           | a3
4           | a4
5           | a5


Product
-------

ProductId | ProductName
-----------------------
1         | p1
2         | p2


ProductAttribute
----------------

ProductId | AttributeId | Value
--------------------------------
1         | 1           | value1
1         | 2           | value2
1         | 3           | value3
1         | 4           | value4
1         | 5           | value5
1         | 1           | value6
1         | 2           | value7
1         | 3           | value8
```

Comment: So am I correct in understanding, you suggest I make 100 tables for each attribute?

Comment: @chief No, you need only 3 tables. I edited my answer with details. See that.

Comment: His attributes are just not on or off, they have values that must be stored with each record.  I don't think the many-to-many relationship is correct.

Comment: How will that handle different types of attributes?  Like price, weight, color, etc.?  Would you store everything as a string?

Comment: @SteveWellens Yes, Everything will be string. It is specified in the question. `Each attribute will be a string`

Comment: Yes, I see that now.  Still, it seems over-normalized if there is a one-to-one relationship between element and attribute and multiple tables are used.  You could put EVERY field in another table, have a single field record (RecordID), and end up with quite a mess. And price as a string?  That is not going to work out well.

Comment: @SteveWellens I suggested this design since he said every attribute is a String. Otherwise, this design may not work well, and I support your comment associated with the question in that case.

Answer (score 0):

XML is best answer. you can still have different attributes for each row.
and data will be available in single query.